# Variable MySql Where query from VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a this query like this:

```
SELECT movimiento_almacen WHERE re_boleta_idre_boleta= XXX
```

I would like to know if there is a way to consult multiple re_boleta_idre_boleta to sort in just one query like this:

```
SELECT movimiento_almacen WHERE re_boleta_idre_boleta= XXX,XXX,XXX
```

But the XXX are variable, sometimes could be only 1 `WHERE` in other query could be 4 `WHERE`...

I was thinking on a procedure that receive an array but I never did and trying to figure how to do it

AND isnt funtional because its variable the query...

Comment: Use an `if` statement? `if` this then use 1 element, `else` add to `array` and use the `array`.

Comment: Thing you want to use the 'in' criteria WHERE re_boleta_idre_boleta IN (XXX,XXX,XXX) https://www.guru99.com/where-clause.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example I wrote some time ago for querying SQL Server based on selections in a `ListBox`:

```vb
Dim connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
Dim command As New SqlCommand
Dim query As New StringBuilder("SELECT * FROM MyTable")
 
Select Case Me.ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count
    Case 1
        query.Append(" WHERE MyColumn = @MyColumn")
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyColumn", Me.ListBox1.SelectedItem)
    Case Is > 1
        query.Append(" WHERE MyColumn IN (")
 
        Dim paramName As String
 
        For index As Integer = 0 To Me.ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count - 1 Step 1
            paramName = "@MyColumn" & index
 
            If index > 0 Then
                query.Append(", ")
            End If
 
            query.Append(paramName)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, Me.ListBox1.SelectedItems(index))
        Next index
 
        query.Append(")")
End Select
 
command.CommandText = query.ToString()
command.Connection = connection
```

In that case, you can end up with three different types of queries:

- No items selected: `SELECT * FROM MyTable`
- One item selected: `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = @MyColumn`
- Multiple items selected: `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn IN (@MyColumn0, @MyColumn1)`

You can use the same code structure with the MySQL ADO.NET provider. You say that you have discrete variables but, however you identify which ones you need to include, I suggest that you place them in an array or collection and then you can use a loop in the same way I have in that code, looping over your array/collection instead of the `SelectedItems` of the `ListBox`.

Comment: Thanks a Lot, this help me a lot!

I was doing as you said, just the IN clause I didnt know but help me just a LOT!

Comment: This help me with the variable part where I was stuck, and the case in VB...

I was thinking to do with store procedures but After this I will do as you say, this is a fully answer!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

To use more than one value you need the `IN`clause

Like so

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT movimiento_almacen WHERE re_boleta_idre_boleta IN (@val1,@val2,@val3)"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", val1.Text )
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", val2.Text )
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4", val3.Text )
Dim reader  = cmd.ExecuteReader()
while reader.Read()
   yourarray = reader(0).ToString()
End While
```

This is a static with three values only, But the commandtext string can be soved in al loop

Comment: That doesn't answer the question as asked because it doesn't allow the number of values to be varied.

Comment: Thanks a Lot, IN clause was the solution, Regards and thanks for your time